# WARNING: git-filter-branch has a glut of gotchas generating mangled history rewrites

Tags: bash, git

I want to clean a large file from my local git repository (and incidentally clean my repository to reduce size). This is my bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
bigfile="/path_to_mygitproject/bigfile.tar.gz"
git filter-branch --force --index-filter 'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch '"$bigfile"'' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
git filter-branch --force --index-filter 'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch '"$bigfile"'' HEAD
```

But now show the following warning:

```
WARNING: git-filter-branch has a glut of gotchas generating mangled history
     rewrites.  Hit Ctrl-C before proceeding to abort, then use an
     alternative filtering tool such as 'git filter-repo'
     (https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/) instead.  See the
     filter-branch manual page for more details; to squelch this warning,
     set FILTER_BRANCH_SQUELCH_WARNING=1.
```

I have always used this bash and have never had a problem. Until now. I guess something changed in git.

I try to replace "git filter-branch" with "git filter-repo" but I get the message:

```
git: 'filter-repo' is not a git command. Look at 'git --help'.but
```

what should i fix? thanks

**Update:**

I did this but it seems that everything changed

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/newren/git-filter-repo/master/git-filter-repo -O /home/user/.local/bin/git-filter-repo
chmod +x /home/user/.local/bin/git-filter-repo
```

And replace in my script "git filter-branch" with "git filter-repo". Out:

```
git-filter-repo: error: argument --prune-empty: expected one argument
git-filter-repo: error: unrecognized arguments: --index-filter git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch bigfile.tar.gz HEAD
```

I checked [the examples](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#EXAMPLES) and I add "--prune-empty auto", but i couldn't fix my script, because I don't know what the alternatives to "--index-filter" or "--tag-name-filter" will be (it seems they don't exist)

```
git filter-repo --version
ffc6fa9265d8
git --version
git version 2.25.1
```

**Update:**

I have managed to reduce the size of my repo with the command:

```
git filter-repo --strip-blobs-bigger-than 10M
```

But it is an unsuitable method, since i can delete other files that are larger than 10M and that I do not want to be deleted

**Solved!**

```
git filter-repo --path bigfile.tar.gz --invert-paths
```

vote close

Comment: Just tried your solution but got this message fromm git: 'filter-repo' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Comment: @AliSafari what's available depends on how your Git was configured. Use a separate question and detail what it is you are using, so people can help.